# Link Button with No History

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a website for a domestic violence agency and I want to include an "escape" button. However, simply having a link leaves a danger of someone looking in the browser's history or clicking the back button to see where they were.

So, my question is: (1) Is it possible to load webpages and exclude them from the history? (2) Is it possible to disable the back button after following a link to, say, Google?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disabling the back button:

```
<script language="text/javascript">

function goNewWin() {

//***Get what is below onto one line***

window.open("backbuttonnewpage.html",'TheNewpop','toolbar=1,
location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,
scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); 

//***Get what is above onto one line*** 

self.close()

}

</script> 

<a href="javascript:goNewWin()">Click to go to a new page</a>
```

from http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911/backbutton.html

Comment: goNewWin forces the user into a new tab/window. It will not be liked if it is allowed. If pop-up blocking is on, then it will just close the current window.

Comment: I removed the second part, after testing it, thx for pointing it out. However, if you're trying to protect someone that has to hide his surfing from someone else, i'm sure a popup hurting the user experience will not be your biggest concern

Comment: As an addendum: I would advise to having a short tutorial on enabling privacy-centric surfing techiques on your site. Since most modern browsers support "private surfing windows" I'd say there's a big chance you can make surfing that bit more safer for half your audience

Answer (score 1):

No.

However, you could detect the browser and then explain details on how to clear history/caches for their current browser.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe and no. That is entirely browser driven. Some browsers have been known to replace pages in history when window.location.replace(newURL) is called, but that is not guaranteed and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first question: As far as I know, the browser's history is completely dependant only on the **browser**'s settings. Websites cannot and (should not) try to access any of the browser's preferences and functionality . A website just provides information (i.e. code and resources) - it is the browser's task to decide what to do with it (how to parse and render it). 
So in my opinion, the best you can do is to suggest the user to clean one's history or use a "private mode". You even might provide information about how to do that, depending on the user's browser.

In any case: All the best for your project against domestic violence!